# How can I switch execution of a command run with specific arguments with another command, but not for other arguments?

Tags: bash

**Q:** How do I replace a system command including its arguments on a Linux system?

Scenario: there is a command on a system which takes arguments.

Example:

```bsh
$ command -a restart
Output: something
```

I'd like to replace the execution of that *specific* command with that *specific* parameter with e.g. `command -a reload && echo hi`. In that way, the command would never execute a restart, but a reload.

Notes:

- Other parameters should not interfere.
  `command -a else` should be executed as `command -a else`.
- Command is executed for the root user only
- I cannot replace the command file itself, as an update of the package would replace it

Is this possible?

Comment: what if it is e.g. `command -b something -a restart` ?

Comment: that won't work.

Comment: What does that mean? Should it print an error? Should it run `command -b something -a reload` instead? Do you mean that the specific command you are thinking of doesn't allow more than one option to be passed? Also, who should this work for? Anyone on the system who runs `command`? Only one specific user?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Only the root user should be fine.
When `command -b something -a reload` is executed, it should execute `command -b something -a reload`. However, `command` only takes a single argument, so it won't really matter.

Comment: Write a shell script named `command`, which checks if options are `-a restart`. If yes, it does its custom thing, if no, it calls the original *command* and passes all options to it. You move the original *command* to an obscure directory and the shell script into a directory in PATH.

Comment: I can't. What if the package of command is updated? It will simply replace the file.

Comment: @KevinC of course you can, you put it another directory in `$PATH` which comes before the directory where this command is. Typically programs from packages go in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`; and `/usr/local/bin` is very commonly used for overriding programs in those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file:

```bsh
my_command_(){
    if [ "$1 $2" = "-a restart" ] ; then
        shift 2
        my_command -a reload "$@"
    else
        my_command "$@"
    fi
}
alias my_command="my_command_"
```

This will also change

`my_command -a restart -b something`
to
`my_command -a reload -b something`.

But it will not change `my_command -b something -a restart`.

---

**System-wide alternative:**

Create a script in another directory in `$PATH` which comes before the directory where this command is and make it executable, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/my_command`, with following content:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1 $2" = "-a restart" ] ; then
    shift 2
    /usr/bin/my_command -a reload "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/my_command "$@"
fi
```

Change `/usr/bin/my_command` to the actual path.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I didn't copy and edited it properly on my system. This works like a charm!

Comment: glad that it works :-)

Comment: Could this also work if it were to be system wide?

Comment: yes, do what @muru commented. I added that option to my answer as well.